# Distribution of function values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> How are the values of $f(x) = x^2$ distributed by uniformly sampling $x \in [0,1]$?

My attempt: The drivative of the inverse function characterizes the sample density in each infinitesimal interval on the codomain of $f$ so the resulting distribution is

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$$

but I couldn't confirm that by numerical simulation. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct density function.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the probabilities directly:

Let $Y = f(X), X\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$

The CDF of $X$ is just the ramp function $F_X(x)= P_X(X\leq x) = x,\;\;x\in[0,1]$

We know $x = \sqrt{y}, \;y\in [0,1]$. Now, what is $F_Y(y)?$

$$F_Y(y)=P_Y(Y\leq y) = P(X\leq \sqrt{y})=\sqrt{y}$$

Since $F_Y$ is differentiable, we can get the density function $f_Y(y)$:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

As you derived.