# What is the right term: "Histogram" of function values

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, terminology

I wonder what the correct technical term for this concept is: It's like a "histogram" or probability density of function values, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342976/distribution-of-function-values). For example, if a particle moves along the trajectory $x(t) = \sin (t)$, the probability density to find the particle at a random time $t_0$ is proportional to
$$P(x) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \sin^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}.$$

[image]

As you see, I'm not talking about a histogram with discrete bins, but some kind of continuous probability density. Another practical is the electrical field strength around a charged point particle. At a distance $\vec{r}$ the electrical field strength is $| \vec{E} | (\vec{r}) = \frac{E_0}{| \vec{r} |^2}$. If I place a probe particle at some random $\vec{r}_0$, the field it experiences $E$ is drawn from a probability distribution proportional to
$$P(E) = -\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}E} V(| \vec{E} | (\vec{r}) > E) = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{{E_0}^3}{E^5}},$$
where $V(| \vec{E} | (\vec{r}) > E) = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3(| \vec{E} | (\vec{r}) = E)$ is the volume of the sphere where the field strength $| \vec{E} | (\vec{r})$ is larger than $E$, and $R(| \vec{E} | (\vec{r}) = E) = \sqrt{\frac{E_0}{E}}$ is that sphere's radius.

So, what is the name of this histogram/probablity density of function values? Is it the same name if the function argument is a vector? How about when the function returns a vector? Then the histogram itself is multidimensional.

Alternatively, if there is no rigorous technical term for the histogram/probability density, is there maybe a term for the process of going from the function $f(x)$ to its histogram $P_f(y)$?

Comment: Histograms are just the graph of a step-function. Step functions can be made left-continuous so they allow you to turn discrete distributions into continuous ones. That interpretation can be really useful in fields like signal processing.

Comment: I definitely agree that this is the continuous analogue of a histogram. Why not simply "(probability) density"? Or "distribution"? (Btw, your specific example is called the "[arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution)".)

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for the link! Interestingly, in that Wikipedia article they don't make a connection to the arcsine distribution being the probability density distribution of a sinusoidally moving object. "Probability density" goes in the right direction, but it sounds like this usage is bound to a random process. If, in the second example, I instead want to describe the differential volume having a field strength between $[E, E+\text{d}E]$, it would be misleading to speak of probability.